# How to run Scrapy Crawler Process parallel in separate processes? (Multiprocessing)

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to do `Multiprocessing` of my `spider`. I know `CrawlerProcess` runs the spider in a single process.

I want to run multiple times the same spider with different arguments.

I tried this but doesn't work.

How do I do multiprocessing?

Please do help. Thanks.

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
import multiprocessing
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

process = CrawlerProcess(settings=get_project_settings())
process.crawl(Spider, data=all_batches[0])

process1 = CrawlerProcess(settings=get_project_settings())
process1.crawl(Spider, data=all_batches[1])

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process.start())
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process1.start())

p1.start()
p2.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run each `scrapy` crawler instance inside a separate process. This is because `scrapy` uses [twisted](https://github.com/twisted/twisted), and you can't use it multiple times in the same process.

Also, you need to disable the telenet extension, because `scrapy` will try to bind to the same port on multiple processes.

Test code:

```
import scrapy
from multiprocessing import Process
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogspider'
    start_urls = ['https://blog.scrapinghub.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        for title in response.css('.post-header>h2'):
            print('my_data -> ', self.settings['my_data'])
            yield {'title': title.css('a ::text').get()}

def start_spider(spider, settings: dict = {}, data: dict = {}):
    all_settings = {**settings, **{'my_data': data, 'TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED': False}}
    def crawler_func():
        crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(all_settings)
        crawler_process.crawl(spider)
        crawler_process.start()
    process = Process(target=crawler_func)
    process.start()
    return process

map(lambda x: x.join(), [
    start_spider(TestSpider, data={'data': 'test_1'}),
    start_spider(TestSpider, data={'data': 'test_2'})
])
```

Comment: It shows that "This code is unreachable" for the map function. Is the indentation wrong in the example? How do I get this running? Many thanks!

Comment: The indentation is fine. Copy the text into a `file.py`and then run it with `python file.py` and it should run. I tested it on Python 3.7.3.

Comment: I copied this above code to a file as is and tried to run it. It says ```Can't pickle local object 'start_spider.<locals>.crawler_func'```

Comment: If you are getting the pickle error above - see the below question. Switching to multiprocess worked for me.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72766345/attributeerror-cant-pickle-local-object-in-multiprocessing