# AsyncIO: AttributeError: Can't pickle local object

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-asyncio, pickle

I am working on code that accesses an api that's not made using asyncio along with a discord bot that uses asyncio. In my dsicord commands I created local functions with the blocking parts of the api and want to run them with `BaseEventLoop.run_in_executer` with a `ProcessPoolExecutor` object.

Example:

```py
@client.command()
def someCommand(...):
    ... processing where lots of local variables are defined

    def task():
        ... blocking code making use of lots of local variables
    
    loop.run_in_executer(processPool, task)
```

Some very useful answers are given around the multiprocessing module [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72766345/attributeerror-cant-pickle-local-object-in-multiprocessing). Are there any similar solutions without moving the functions to global space where a lot of unwanted clutter will be created :( ? Having the blocking functions defined locally makes the code more clean and readable. I already have hundreds of functions in my file and don't want to add unnecessary global space clutter.

Comment: How is it more cluttered defining the same function globally? Put a leading `_` on it (to indicate it's not part of the public API), and it won't show up in tab-completion or the like (you could also define `__all__` for the module for the same purpose if you prefer). Also, if the code is blocking, could you just use a `ThreadPoolExecutor`? `ProcessPoolExecutor`s are more important when the code is CPU-bound, but if it's blocking code, it likely isn't, and threads are likely fine (since it's only using local variables, not shared global state).

Comment: `I already have hundreds of functions in my file` how about creating more files ? you can search for `python project structure` to see how to structure your project, which is probably the bigger problem, and the error you are seeing is caused by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your options are to use [loky](https://github.com/joblib/loky) or [pathos](https://pypi.org/project/pathos/) which can serialize local functions by using cloudpickle or dill (and have a slight overhead over normal python pools), but they are low level APIs unlike `concurrent.futures` which is a high level API, so you will have to do some wrapping yourself using `asyncio.run_in_executor` with a threadpool that will be wrapping the low level pools.

Comment: *Only* option? `dill` is a thing, and I'm fairly sure there are other options besides that.

Comment: @ShadowRanger for a multiprocessing framework you'd have to use `pathos` in order to use `dill` and its behavior is weirder than `loky` ... but i'll add that in the answer.

Comment: Using loky or dill is a solution to make serializing local functions possible, but the solution I opted to which resulted in cleaner code was to make my api library asynchronous